# Fiddler how to remove HTTPS extensions?

Tags: ssl, https, fiddler, sni

I'm attempting to strip TLS SNI headers. How can I manipulate HTTPS extensions using Fiddlerscript?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the .NET Framework does not expose the level of granularity you require for the `SslStream` class (and Windows itself doesn't make it easy either). The only way you can achieve what you're looking for with Fiddler today is to disable TLS1 and offer only Ssl3.

To update your FiddlerScript, click Rules > Customize Rules. Scroll down to the Main() function and add the following line within the function:

```
CONFIG.oAcceptedServerHTTPSProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl3;
```

Comment: Highly unfortunate, given the recent attack on SSL3. I think the reason I was earlier able to bypass the SNI blocking was because Firefox retried down to SSL3, which cannot be per-site-blocked through SNI, and is now disabled for security purposes.

Comment: I'm not sure what `SNI blocking` you're referring to specifically? It actually may be able to get Fiddler to suppress SNI through a bit of hackery (since SNI isn't supposed to be sent for requests to an IP-literal address) but it's slightly tricky to get this right and I'd be interested to learn why this is of interest before putting it together.

Comment: Avoiding web censorship which blocks TLS using SNI when an IP address is shared between unblocked and blocked sites. Tor is rather slow for this purpose.